# How to use curl in android app development

Tags: android, json, curl

I am trying to make an android application which will use clarifai api , in documentation it says use rest and curl and i have no idea what to do in android development,where to write curl code and how to get json response. Can anyone tell me a solution?

Comment: Curl is something you'd use on your PC to test a webservice API.  Its not something you'd use in Android.  Its a command line tool that sends HTTP requests

Answer (score 0):

Actually from android, there are several library that will help you do REST request, you don't have to use curl specifically.

You have for instance [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/), or [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/). Also, after some searching, Clarifai actually has a java SDK that you can integrate to your project, with a quickstart guide on how to do it: https://clarifai.com/developer/quick-start/, just select Java from the code window and you'll have everything explained

Comment: You wouldn't use curl at all.  Curl is a command line tool.  The equivalent in android is HttpUrlConnection